# How can I prove that $\frac{x}{x^2 - 4}$is invertible?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Prove that $$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2-4}$$ is invertible in $(-2,2)$.

I´m trying to proof this using the definition of injective function:
$$\frac{x}{x^2-4}=\frac{y}{y^2-4} \rightarrow x=y$$ but I couldn´t prove this definition.

Comment: You've tagged this as [tag:calculus], so have you considered the derivative?

Comment: I didn´t do the derivate because this is a problem for a introductory course of calculus, I can´t use derivation

Answer (score 7):

Solution 1: See that the derivative is strictly negative.

---

Solution 2: Rewrite the function as

$$2 f(x) = \frac{1}{x + 2} + \frac{1}{x - 2}$$

that is, a sum of decreasing functions on the given interval.

Answer (score 4):

For $x$ and $y$ in our interval, we have
$$\frac{x}{x^2-4}=\frac{y}{y^2-4}\quad\text{if and only if}\quad x(y^2-4)=y(x^2-4).$$
This can be rewritten as $xy^2-yx^2+4(y-x)=0$, and then as
$$(xy+4)(y-x)=0.$$
In our interval, we cannot have $xy+4=0$, so $y=x$.

Comment: Good answer! thank you

Comment: You are welcome. The derivative is also a very good way to proceed. And there are ways other than the derivative to show the function is decreasing in our interval.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{x^2-4}=\frac{-x^2-4}{\left(x^2-4\right)^2}$
Since the derivative is always negative and has no singularities inside the interval, it must be monotonous, thus invertible.